# How to represent stereo audio data for FFT

Tags: fft

How should stereo (2 channel) audio data be represented for FFT? Do you

A. Take the average of the two channels and assign it to the real component of a number and leave the imaginary component 0.

B. Assign one channel to the real component and the other channel to the imag component.

Is there a reason to do one or the other? I searched the web but could not find any definite answers on this.

I'm doing some simple spectrum analysis and, not knowing any better, used option A). This gave me an unexpected result, whereas option B) went as expected. Here are some more details:

I have a WAV file of a piano "middle-C". By definition, middle-C is 260Hz, so I would expect the peak frequency to be at 260Hz and smaller peaks at harmonics. I confirmed this by viewing the spectrum via an audio editing software (Sound Forge). But when I took the FFT myself, with option A), the peak was at 520Hz. With option B), the peak was at 260Hz.

Am I missing something? The explanation that I came up with so far is that representing stereo data using a real and imag component implies that the two channels are independent, which, I suppose they're not, and hence the mess-up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option B does not make sense. Option A, which amounts to convert the signal to mono, is OK (if you are interested in a global spectrum). 
Your problem (double freq) is surely related to some misunderstanding in the use of your FFT routines.

Comment: In fact it does make a lot of sense. See the answer of that question for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14477454/apply-fft-to-a-both-channels-of-a-stereo-signal-seperately

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you're taking the average correctly.  :-)

C. Process each channel separately, assigning the amplitude to the real component and leaving the imaginary component as 0.

Comment: Or just use a real-optimized FFT - most tool kits offer one, and it would prevent confusion about real and imaginary component, at least for the input ;)

Some even offer "n-dimensional" variants; Think of each channel of your sound input as one dimension. Of course, you'd have to find the average of the FFT results afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

Once you take the FFT you need to get the Magnitude of the complex frequency spectrum. To get the magnitude you take the absolute of the complex spectrum |X(w)|. If you want to look at the power spectrum you square the magnitude spectrum, |X(w)|^2.

In terms of your frequency shift I think it has to do with you setting the imaginary parts to zero. 
If you imagine the complex Frequency spectrum as a series of complex vectors or position vectors in a cartesian space. If you took one discrete frequency bin X(w), there would be one real component representing its direction in the real axis (x -direction), and one imaginary component in the in the imaginary axis (y - direction). There are four important values about this discrete frequency, 1. real value, 2. imaginary value, 3. Magnitude  and, 4. phase. If you just take the real value and set imaginary to 0, you are setting Magnitude = real and phase = 0deg or 90deg. You have hence forth modified the resulting spectrum, and applied a bias to every frequency bin. Take a look at the wiki on [Magnitude of a vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnitude_%28vector%29), also called the Euclidean norm of a vector to brush up on your understanding. Leonbloy was correct, but I hope this was more informative.

Comment: I think you're confused about when OP is setting the imaginary part to zero, namely in the input of the FFT. This is perfectly okay, because audio data doesn't have an imaginary part, whereas the transformed data does.
As soon as the FFT is done, you're right, of course. You'd need to calculate the magnitude, rather than just the real part.
I think the misunderstanding leonbloy was playing at has more to do with the labeling of the frequency bins than with the norm :)

Answer (score 0):

Think of the FFT as a way to get information from a single signal. What you are asking is what is the best way to display data from two signals. My answer would be to treat each independently, and display an FFT for each.

If you want a really fast streaming FFT you can read about an algorithm I wrote here: www.depthcharged.us/?p=176